# Problems with interaction between spring boot and extjs frontend

Tags: spring, spring-boot, extjs

I set up a project with *Spring Boot 2.7* as backend and *extjs 7.0.0* GPL as frontend.

I can send requests from extjs store to the backend (via jsonp e.g.), but unfortunately I really don't achieve to send requests from the spring boot backend to the extjs controller, i.e. stores.

I tried some approaches like *urlrewrite* or the integration of php code in the */webapp* folder, but nothing of this was a solution for my problem.

Anyboy could give me some hints in order to solve my problem, please?
Greetings and thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
Ok, after preparing and facing other issues, I'm back to the above mentioned issue only...

[First of all here my project structure in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQjtj.png)

Here the code of Spring Boot *application.properties*

```html
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=MyBankingApp
server.servlet.context-path=/MyBankingApp
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false


#Database Configrations
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxx/mybanking
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

#Multipart
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
```

Here Spring Boot Application class with the main method

```js
package com.mybanking;

import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyBankingApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyBankingApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments arg0) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello World from MyBankingApp Runner");
    }   

}
```

Here the code of the extjs class of the relevant store

```js
Ext.define('MyBankingApp.store.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    xtype: 'userStore',
    id:'userStoreID',
    requires: [
        'MyBankingApp.model.User'
    ],
    
    autoLoad: false,
    model: 'MyBankingApp.model.User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url:'http://localhost:8080/MyBankingApp/user',
        //scope: this,
        callbackKey: 'callback'
    },
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {  
            alert(success);                                           
            alert(records);
    },
    scope: this
});
```

and its corresponding java controller

```js
package com.mybanking.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.mybanking.model.LoginUser;
import com.mybanking.model.User;
import com.mybanking.repository.UserRepository;
import com.mybanking.service.LoginUserService;
import com.mybanking.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showUser(@RequestParam String _dc, 
            @RequestParam String callback, 
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
        
        var user = (List<User>) userService.showUser();
        System.out.println("callback:\n");
        System.out.println(callback);
        String user_json = new Gson().toJson(user);
        callback += user_json;
        System.out.println(callback + '\n');

        return callback;
        
    }
}
```

Here the extjs view, where the UserStore is explicitely loaded in order to show the data retrieved from backend - what does not function

```js
Ext.define('MyBankingApp.view.user.User', { 
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    xtype: 'userView', 
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),    
    controller: 'userController', 
    layout: 'border',
    title: 'User',  
    autoShow: true, 
    items: [{ 
        xtype : 'tabpanel',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        title : 'MyBankingApp',
        region : 'center',
        controller: 'userController',    
        items : [{          
            title: 'User',
            //collapsible: true,
          items : [{
            //xtype : 'grid',
            xtype : 'window',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            region : 'center',
            title : 'User List',
            header : true,
            store: 'MyBankingApp.store.User',
            columns: [{ 
                text: 'ID', 
                //width: 100, 
                sortable: false, 
                dataIndex: 'id' 
            }, 
            { 
                text: 'Name', 
                //width: 100, 
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, 
            { 
                text: 'Created', 
                flex: 1, 
                dataIndex: 'created',
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y-m-d')
            }],
            dockedItems: [{ 
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                store: 'MyBankingApp.store.User',
                dock: 'bottom', 
                displayInfo: true
            }],
            listeners: {
                beforerender: function() {              
                    
                    var store = Ext.getStore('MyBankingApp.store.User');
                    store.load();                                                       
                    console.log(store); 
                            
                    var url = store.getProxy().url;
                    var params = store.getProxy().extraParams;      
                    console.log(url);
                    console.log(params);                
                    
                    /*
                    Ext.data.StoreManager.each( function(store) {
                          console.log(store.id);
                        });
                    */                              
                }
            }
        }],
        },
        {
            title: 'User',
            html: 'Tab content User'
        }],     
        buttons: [{ 
            text: 'Hello', 
            listeners: { 
                click: 'onClickButton' 
            } 
        }],     
        buttons: [{ 
            text: 'Logout', 
            listeners: { 
                click: 'onClickButton1' 
            } 
        }]
    }]
});
```

Here the error message thrown by the backend when I visit the UserView, where the store should be loaded:

```html
2022-07-07 20:31:19.024  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] com.mybanking.ServletInitializer         : Starting ServletInitializer v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.15.1 on WIN-86UTNGFROLK with PID 8272 (C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MyBankingApp\WEB-INF\classes started by Administrator in C:\Windows\system32)
2022-07-07 20:31:19.029  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] com.mybanking.ServletInitializer         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-07-07 20:31:20.545  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-07-07 20:31:20.667  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 98 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-07-07 20:31:21.498  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/MyBankingApp]  : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-07-07 20:31:21.498  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2348 ms
2022-07-07 20:31:22.432  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-07-07 20:31:22.643  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2022-07-07 20:31:23.154  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-07-07 20:31:23.399  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Starting...
2022-07-07 20:31:23.617  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Start completed.
2022-07-07 20:31:23.659  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2022-07-07 20:31:24.953  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-07-07 20:31:24.974  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-07-07 20:31:27.383  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] com.mybanking.ServletInitializer         : Started ServletInitializer in 9.929 seconds (JVM running for 7520.221)
Hello World from MyBankingApp Runner
2022-07-07 20:31:27.436  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/MyBankingApp]  : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcher'
2022-07-07 20:31:27.437  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
2022-07-07 20:31:28.179  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 742 ms
2022-07-07 20:31:28.229  INFO 8272 --- [alina-utility-1] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Reloading Context with name [/MyBankingApp] is completed
2022-07-07 20:31:40.935  INFO 8272 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/MyBankingApp]  : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-07-07 20:31:40.936  INFO 8272 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-07-07 20:31:40.937  INFO 8272 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
callback:

Ext.data.JsonP.callback1
Ext.data.JsonP.callback1[{"id":1,"name":"user1","created":"2022-07-07 22:18:27.561538"},{"id":2,"name":"user2","created":"2022-07-07 22:18:39.292204"}]

2022-07-07 20:31:41.966 ERROR 8272 --- [io-8080-exec-11] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-11] Exception processing template "Ext.data.JsonP.callback1[{"id":1,"n[...]2:18:27.561538"},{"id":2,"name":"user2","created":"2022-07-07 22:18:39.292204"}]": Error resolving template [Ext.data.JsonP.callback1[{"id":1,"name":"user1","created":"2022-07-07 22:18:27.561538"},{"id":2,"name":"user2","created":"2022-07-07 22:18:39.292204"}]], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [Ext.data.JsonP.callback1[{"id":1,"name":"user1","created":"2022-07-07 22:18:27.561538"},{"id":2,"name":"user2","created":"2022-07-07 22:18:39.292204"}]], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.63]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2022-07-07 20:31:41.969 ERROR 8272 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/user] due to exception [Error resolving template [Ext.data.JsonP.callback1[{"id":1,"name":"user1","created":"2022-07-07 22:18:27.561538"},{"id":2,"name":"user2","created":"2022-07-07 22:18:39.292204"}]], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers]

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [Ext.data.JsonP.callback1[{"id":1,"name":"user1","created":"2022-07-07 22:18:27.561538"},{"id":2,"name":"user2","created":"2022-07-07 22:18:39.292204"}]], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.63]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

So now:

- I'm testing on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2022, with same results
- I'm developing in Eclipse / Spring Tool Suite 4
- I'm testing with sencha app watch (localhost:1841) and Eclipse Tomcat 9 (localhost:8080) and also on a separate Tomcat 9 (localhost:80) instance
- The exception shown above clearly says, that Spring tries to return the response to a Spring template and not to the sender (which isn't known by the backend)
- But it also says, that the data could be retrieved successfully from the database, as it is shown in the built json string (2 sets)

But there do exist solutions in order to get what I want: Spring returns back its responses to Extjs, but I really don't know how I could achieve it.

Apart from the approaches I tried without success, I had to work with a similar project config like mine some years ago, but I really don't remember the details...

Comment: Posting your code and stating the exact problem you have with it will get you the answer much faster.

Comment: Unless you are using web sockets, the communication between ExtJs and the backend is in one direction: Frontend to backend. ExtJs requests works very good, so you could better check your API first to see if it is delivering the expected results. And yes, publishing your code will help more.

Comment: Ok, thank you for those hints, I'll post some relevant code and other observations

Comment: Just did some edits and hopefully my post can be better understood now